# Questions about DefineClass and my attempted usage of it

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, jnienv

I'm trying to create a class/inject a class inside a java process through injecting a DLL into the process and using JNI to interface with java.

I came across a function called DefineClass but i can't quite get it work how i expected it to, so i have a few questions about the parameters the functions take:

1. In my case, what do i pass as class loader?
2. It accepts a byte array and its length as the "content" of the class, what would be the correct way of getting these bytes?
3. Which parts of the class is to be included in the array of bytes? Do i include everything or strip away parts?

Everything i have tried so far has resulted in the function returning null, so I'm not sure where to begin looking. If anyone would include some example usage or important notes about the usage that would be amazing!

```cpp
jobject defined = jni->DefineClass("ChatFormatting", NULL, reach_buf, 4132);

if (defined == nullptr) {
   std::cout << "Defined is NULL." << std::endl;
} else {
   std::cout << "Success!" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get only class name and its' member entries addresses are incorrect.
Before inject, you must change addresses of entries by injectee module address.